# How to find and replace values between specific characters in a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the most efficient way natural to Python, to find all instances of a string within another string surrounded by a `$$` sign and replace it with another value in another variable.

The string in question is like this `"$$firstOccurance$$ some other words here then $$secondOccurance$$"`

My solution below is not working, I think because it's not able to differentiate between the first time it finds the `$$` sign and the second time it finds it again. This results in nothing getting printed. There can be many occurrences of strings between the `$$` value.

```
the_long_string = "$$firstOccurance$$ some other words here then $$secondOccurance$$"
replacement_value = "someNewString"
print(the_long_string[the_long_string.index('$$')+len('$$'):the_long_string.index('$$')])
```

What would be the way to correct and fix what I have done so far?
The end result has to look like this `someNewString some other words here then someNewString`, where there is no `$$` sign left.

Comment: You can find an index starting from a given position, read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index). But maybe this is a job for a [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)?

Comment: This replacement value should replace those between `$$`?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR yes it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example building on @mbuchove's example. Use the regex package (re) to make it easier for you.

The key is you need to use [re.sub()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp#sub) to find and replace all matches.

```py
import re

the_long_string = "$$firstOccurance$$ some other words here then $$secondOccurance$$"
replacement_value = "someNewString"
the_long_string = re.sub("\$\$\w+\$\$", replacement_value, the_long_string)

print(the_long_string)
```

---

If you want to continue with the search manually (without regex), you would need to do something a lot more complicated, still finding all of the $$[n]Occurence$$ by hand.

```py
prev_index = -1
search_start = 0
index = the_long_string.find("$$", search_start)
while index != -1:
    print(index)

    # Closing set of $$
    if prev_index != -1:
        end_index = index + len("$$")
        value_to_replace = the_long_string[prev_index:end_index]
        the_long_string = the_long_string.replace(value_to_replace, replacement_value)
        prev_index = -1 # Reset the search for an opening set of $$
        
    # Opening set of $$
    else:
        prev_index = index
    
    # Check for the next match
    search_start = index + len("$$")
    index = the_long_string.find("$$", search_start)
print(the_long_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use a regular expression substitution:

`re.sub(r'\$\$\w+\$\$', replacement_value, the_long_string)`

Comment: the f and e were a typo, fixed them. \w is a good shortcut